# Get selected items in External list in sharepoint 2010 on server side code using c#

Tags: 2010

I have external list in sharepoint 2010. I want to fetch selected items in external list on button click from outside using C# code.

Any idea how to do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On a button Click Event write the following code:

```
string = "siteUrl";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("listName");

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
//leave query as blank if there is no condition
camlQuery.ViewXml = "";
ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.Load(collListItem);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
{
    //YOU CAN GET THE REST FIELDS IN THE SAME NAME HERE
    oListItem["Title"];
}
```